# Kubernetes on Azure: assign different external IP to different services

Tags: azure, kubernetes, external

I create a sample setup of Kubernets cluster on Azure using Azure Container Service, and it did its job just fine. I set up several containers and services within the Kubernetes, no problem with that.

What makes me fuzzy is that if, say, I run **several nginx containers and want to expose it via different external IPs**, I can't do that for what I know and understand.

[Azure approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-load-balancing) is that I can set up Service and set `type: LoadBalancer` and as I create it Azure will "connect" LoadBalancer attached to client nodes to my service.

But this way I can only attach **one** external IP to **all** of my services which is not something I need. In my example when I run several nginx containers I'd like to expose its 80/tcp ports on different IPs so I can these IPs in DNS, not on different ports of the single IP.

How can I overcome that? **Please help!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure container service, to expose a kubernetes service to Internet, we should use Azure Load balancer. As Radek said, several containers in one pod, and use the same load balancer to keep HA.

If you want to expose several containers to Internet with different Public IP addresses, we can create several pods, and expose them to Internet, in this way, containers with different public IP addresses.

The relationship about pod, containers and node, like this:
[image]

We create several containers in one pod, several pods in one node(host), several pods work for one service. A service works as a cluster, one service with one public IP address.

So, if you want to create several nginx containers with different public IP addresses, we can create several services to archive this:

Create one or two nginx containers in one service, and expose several services to Internet.

```
root@k8s-master-7273A780-0:~# kubectl run jasonnginx --replicas=1 --image nginx
root@k8s-master-7273A780-0:~# kuberctl run mynginx --replicas=2 --image nginx
root@k8s-master-7273A780-0:~# kubectl expose deployments mynginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
root@k8s-master-7273A780-0:~# kubectl expose deployments jasonnginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
root@k8s-master-7273A780-0:~# kubectl get svc
NAME         CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)        AGE
jasonnginx   10.0.114.116   52.168.176.18   80:30153/TCP   5m
kubernetes   10.0.0.1       <none>          443/TCP        15m
mynginx      10.0.205.127   13.82.102.171   80:31906/TCP   6m
root@k8s-master-7273A780-0:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jasonnginx-1417538491-v79mw   1/1       Running   0          20m
mynginx-1396894033-78njj      1/1       Running   0          21m
mynginx-1396894033-pmhjh      1/1       Running   0          21m
```

We can find the Load balancer frontend IP settings(two public IP addresses) via Azure portal:
[image]

Comment: Here is the problem: if, as an example, I delete service and then recreate it as a whole rollup process, will I get **the same** IP for the same service, or **new** IP? Is there any way I can be sure that specific IP (say the one that's I already ordered in Azure Portal) be bind to specific service inside the Kubernetes?

Comment: @Alexander After we delete this service, Azure will recycle this Public IP address, we can't keep this IP address. after we new another service, we will get a new IP address. For now, we can't specify the public IP address.

Comment: @jason-ye-msft So there is some shadow connaction between Kubernetes and Azure which can not be controlled by me as a user, so I can not delete Service in Kubernetes in any case if I don't want to loose the IP? May there be any docs for that?

Comment: What's strange, I created several services in Kubernetes on Azure (so LoadBalacer got extra IPs for these services) and delete these services afterward, Azure won't released these IPs back to the pool. I don't know if "garbage collection" happen one moment (every hour or day, maybe) so far.

Comment: @Alexander As far as I know, we should wait for few mins, Azure will released those IPs.

Comment: Yes, it is so, there is some timeout befor garbage collection started

Comment: @JasonYe what if the node IP address should belong to a private network?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your linked Azure docs, it does not seem like it really differs from it should do on any cloud. I think you miss understood how it is supposed to be used.

When you create a service of any type, it is intended to provide **service** that does not differ. If it's pointing to multiple endpoints, it does that to LoadBalance traffic and provide HA. There is zero reason for this to be exposed externally on an IP per endpoint basis.

But, if you need to expose **different** services on different IPs, you just create both services as LoadBalancer service type, and every svc should receive its unique external load balancer (thus IP).

The behaviour you described (one loadbalancer, multiple services exposed externally) sounds much closer to what you can accomplish with Ingress/IngressController.

Comment: Quite an idea, while I see I have no control over IP acquisition. That is, as I add another svc the Azure Load Balancer gets another IP for my new service (and if I run 5 services that uses port 80/tcp it gets 5 new IPs), while I have no control or even idea which is the rule that connects given external IP to giver service. So if I delete and recreate the same service I have no control over if new or same IP be used. Hard to use this "random" IP, you see. What is your way of doing it?

Comment: To serve external traffic I use Ingress/IngressController, this means I efectively have one serviceexposed with LoadBalancer service (the nginx ingress controller) and all the other services are exposed by means of Ingress. Meaning all of them show up on the same IP with name based vhosts.

Comment: Also, in some cases it is possible to control the IP you get assigned on LB service with `loadBalancerIP: <ip>`, dnto know how it is on Azure though